# Closing empty tags: XHTML5 or HTML5? Why one over the other?

Tags: html, xhtml

After reading extensively about HTML5 and XHTML5 and after reading this post: [Are (non-void) self-closing tags valid in HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558119/are-non-void-self-closing-tags-valid-in-html5?rq=1) , I have got a very simple question:

"Is there a reason why it would be good to serialise HTML5 as XML?"

I understand:

- the differences between HTML, XHTML, XML and HTML5
- that it's good practice to nest elements correctly, use lower case letters, quote attributes, close tags etc...
- that HTML5 has no DTD while XHTML has got a DTD and an XML parse
- that if I specify a page as XHTML5 (HTML5 doctype + XHTML schema) some browsers might not process the page for minor errors etc...

So the question is:

"In which case would it be good to follow very strict XML rules when doing an HTML5 page?"

Above all when it comes to things like

1) The void elements

```
<img src="asdsad.jpg" /> compared with <img src="asdsad.jpg">
<area> compared with <area />
<meta> comparted with <meta/>
```

2) Checked, download etc.. like

```
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" checked> VS
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" checked="checked" />
```

Should I just write following the HTML5 standard and implement as much common sense as possible (lower case, good nesting) or is there A GOOD REASON for a standard company website to be coded in XHTML5?

Comment: *Empty elements can be "closed" in the opening tag like this: `<br />`. HTML5 does not require empty elements to be closed. But if you want stricter validation, or if you need to make your document readable by XML parsers, you must close all HTML elements properly.* source: [w3schools.com/html/html_elements.asp](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_elements.asp#w3-example)

Answer (score 2):

I'd say it's mostly about errors. If you always write perfect HTML, it really doesn't matter which mime type+syntax pair you choose.

When a page might contain errors though, each syntax has alternative benefits

The regular HTML syntax (served as text/html) means using a parser that will try to make the best of your errors. Your content will get rendered somehow, and in many cases, in the way that you intended. However, when it doesn't, debugging it can be made more difficult by the surprising fix-ups that the parser can make.

With the XHTML syntax (served as application/xhtml+xml) the opposite is true. If you make a syntax error, the parser will just stop. In a browser, you'll see either an error message or just the content up to the point where the syntax error was detected. Other kinds of errors though, can be easier to debug because the XML parser won't monkey about with your elements trying to fix the mistake.

To give an example, suppose you have

```
<style> td { font-weight:bold } </style>
<table>
  <tr>
  <td>
  <span>First</span>
  </td>
  <span>Second</span>
  </tr>
</table>
```

That's an HTML content model error because the second span is not in a td element. But it's not an XHTML syntax error (i.e. it's XML well-formed), so the XML parser won't stop on it.

If you use HTML syntax & mime type, what you'll see in a browser is

Second
 **First**

because the HTML parser will move the second span completely out of the table. In more complicated tables, it can be hard to work out how that order has come about.

If you use the XHTML syntax and mime type, what you'll see in a browser is

**First** Second

If you then wonder why "Second" isn't in bold, you can find the appropriate markup more easily because everything's displayed in the order it's placed in the markup.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, after a lot of thinking I decided to go for the xhtml5 syntax without specifying application/xhtml+xml. Basically try to validate all the code as xhtml5 but then serve it as text/html. On the W3C website they say closing slashes will be "accepted".

Comment: They will, on void elements only, but that's the worst possible option. It's an old article now, but much of it still holds true: you should read [Sending XHTML as text/html Considered Harmful](https://hixie.ch/advocacy/xhtml)

Comment: @Alohci Which is an even much older article.

Comment: @connexo - I meant Hixie's article is an old one. From 2002 I believe. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: For example, one practical problem with using the XHTML syntax with a HTML filetype is that you cannot use the full XML syntax. For instance, `<![CDATA[ .. ]]>` will be treated as a malformed comment in HTML and its contents will not be used. Ditto with XML declarations like `<?xml .. ?>` and `<?xml-stylesheet .. ?>`.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Alohci's excellent answer, let me run by your bullet points briefly...

> I understand:
> (..)
>
> - that it's good practice to nest elements correctly, use lower case letters, quote attributes, close tags etc...

Quoting attributes is always a good idea, as well as having no errors, but the rest really doesn't matter. Sure, it's fashionable these days to write tags and attributes in lowercase, but that by itself doesn't make it good practice. Not that uppercase is better, but I'm just saying. By the way, tag names are stored by the browser in the DOM as uppercase in HTML.

> - that HTML5 has no DTD while XHTML has got a DTD and an XML parse

Well, XHTML5 doesn't have a DTD. It does use the XML parser, and that means you can't use entity references such as `&nbsp;`. If you want to use references with XHTML, use numerical references like `&#160;` or revert to an older version that has a DTD.

> - that if I specify a page as XHTML5 (HTML5 doctype + XHTML schema) some browsers might not process the page for minor errors etc...

No browsers tolerate errors in XHTML these days. There used to be browsers that could treat XHTML as HTML, but those no longer exist.

Comment: Thanks, just realised I need to change all the &egrave; &eacute; into either numbered entities or directly inputing them into the file!

Answer (score -3):

Typically when using web technologies you want to use json, not xml. Json has the same serializing capabilities and uses less characters so it’s lighter.

Comment: OK just read about this https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_xml.asp (never used Json before), so you would suggest to follow the HTML5 rather than XHTML5 because I would never use an XML parser in a standard website,correct?

Comment: I’m saying if the recipient or sender of the data you want to interchange is a web service, then use Json. And there’s only 1 way to write json.